# How to count words of a specified number of Lines?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I faced an interesting question to count the words from a file where the number of lines were also specified as a command line argument.
For example if the input text file had -

```
Unix is an OS
Linux is the child of Unix
Unix is fun.
End of File
```

The command to be executed is:

```
bash test.sh unix.txt 3
```

where `unix.txt` is the test file containing the sentences and 3 is the number of lines whose words are to be counted. The answer would be 13.

I have used the basic `wc` commands but none of them would give the correct answer.

So, I tried to use a for loop, but I could not specify how to take only those number of lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `head -n 3 unix.txt` you get the first three lines of your file and then you can pipe them to `wc`

So for any arbitrary filename stored in the `$file` shell variable:

```
{ head -n 3 | wc -w; } < "$file"
```

Or:

```
head -n 3 -- "$file" | wc -w
```

Though the latter wouldn't work with a file called `-` with some `head` implementations, and output `0` in addition to an error message (by `head`) when the file can't be opened, and the failure exit status in that case would be lost unless you use the (non-standard) `pipefail` option found in some shells.

Comment: Should it be like this - `head -n $2 $file | wc -w` where the specified number is the second command line argument and file is the variable with the name of the text file ?

Comment: Yes, I want it be print all the words upto the 3rd line if 3 is specified.

Answer (score 4):

Try also

```
awk -v"LNR=$2" 'NR > LNR {print SUM; exit} {SUM+=NF}' file
13
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do it by `awk`

```
awk '{print NF}' unix.txt
```

Word count along with lines

```
awk '{print NF" "$0}' unix.txt
```

Word count with line numbers

```
awk '$0="line"NR": "NF'  unix.txt
awk '$0="line"NR": "NF'  unix.txt | grep line3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script takes two arguments ,

So , in the script , you can use it like below :

```
sed -n "/\w/{1,$2 p;}"  $1 | wc -w
```

where `$1` contains your file name
 `$2` contains your total number of lines need to search